# Javascript path issue asp.net mvc

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I'm creating an application in asp.net mvc.
I know i can use

```
 @Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.5.1.min.js")
```

to get my path right while adding javascript to my razor file.
but i have javascript reference inside another javascipt file like below

```
$.include('Scripts/jquery.cycle.all.min.js')
$.include('Scripts/jquery.cookie.js')
```

now when i access my default url, my jquery works fine.but when i use any Controller.MEthod url I get jquery errors.

I'm pretty sure its some path issue.My application is not getting the JS which is included inside another JS file's path right when i use any controller/method url.

kindly help..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be because

```
$.include('Scripts/jquery.cookie.js')
```

is a relative path (relative to the controller you're currently in) while

```
@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.5.1.min.js")
```

is an absolute path.

Try and look in Firebug in the "Net" tab to see where exactly ***where*** your application trying to find the scripts you're missing

**EDIT:**
I wouldn't be surprised if while in a /home/whatever (controller/action) your application will look for **jquery.cookie.js** in

```
/home/whatever/scripts/jquery.cookie.js
```

**EDIT #2**
Try and specify an absolute path in your js file. Something like this

```
$.include('../scripts/jquery.cookie.js')
```

User "../" to navigate to the root of your application. Let's say that ***jquery.cookie.js*** is located in ***cnd/scripts/*** you should do something like

```
$.include('../../scripts/jquery.cookie.js')
```

Comment: I checked,When i'm in root url it takes path correctly from localhost/scripts/jquery.cookie.js.but when i access localhost/controller/method it is searching js file in localhost/controller/scripts/jquery.cookie.js.How can i fix it?any ideas?

Comment: Edited my answer. Let me know if you need anymore help

Comment: hey,$.include('../scripts/jquery.cookie.js') solved my problem.no jquery error now.thanks.

Comment: Glad I could help :). Remember to user firebug "net" (or chrome "network") tab in these type of situations. It really helps